# How to just get the content of the tag when you use findAll in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So on the project I'm building I want to find the price contained on the multiple results I got with the `findAll()` command. Here's the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 
price = soup.find_all(class_='search-result__market-price--value')
print(price)
```

And this is what I get:

```
[<span class="search-result__market-price--value" tabindex="-1"> $0.11 </span>, <span class="search-result__market-price--value" tabindex="-1"> $0.24 </span>, ... ]
```

I tried using this code I found somewhere else `price = soup.find_all(class_='search-result__market-price--value')[0].string` but it just gave the error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

What can I do to just get the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate the `ResultSet` created by `find_all()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 
for price in soup.find_all(class_='search-result__market-price--value'):
    print(price.text)
```

or to *just get the numbers*

```
    print(price.text.split('$')[-1])
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<span class="search-result__market-price--value" tabindex="-1"> $0.11 </span>
<span class="search-result__market-price--value" tabindex="-1"> $0.24 </span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(tag.text.split('$')[-1])
```

###### Output

```
0.11 
0.24
```